# Google Cloud DataCatalog

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to do a PoC on Data Catalog service in GCP.

I've gone through the GCLOUD reference at link:

> https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/data-catalog

And tried creating tag template and searching for big query tables based on column name using Data Catalog search syntax.

But I was not able to find any command to get the number of rows of big query tables (search on technical metadata). If someone has tried this, please guide me in the right direction!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like `bq ls | grep table | wc -l`

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_ls

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/data-catalog/search#EXAMPLES

Answer (score 0):

At the time of this answer, Data Catalog does not have the number of rows natively, you would need to:

1. Create a Tag Template with a field for numbers_rows.
2. Tag your Big Query Table in Data Catalog with the value.

This quickstart guide may help you doing the two steps:
https://cloud.google.com/data-catalog/docs/quickstart-tagging#gcloud-command

If you are looking for Python code, this example may help you:
[datacatalog_tag_factory.py](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/datacatalog-connectors-rdbms/blob/master/rdbms2datacatalog/src/google/datacatalog_connectors/rdbms/prepare/datacatalog_tag_factory.py#L83)

You would also need a scheduled batch process to keep this tag field updated.